# C++ Do-While logic is right but doesn't run correctly

Tags: c++, loops, do-while

The code is simple. It users Pointers to receive the input for the amount of rows and columns to be displayed in a multiplication table. I tried to have a validation system using a Do-While loop but it doesn't seem to work. Even if the values entered are outside the range it still accepts it and moves on, thus printing an incorrect table.

How can I fix this? I don't want to change the method being used too much because the way it is now is clean and simple. Is there a simple fix to this or should I just redo the logic entirely?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

int passByRow(int *x);
int passByColumn(int *x);

int main()
{
    int row = 0, column = 0;
    int dummy;

    do // Input Row
    {
        passByRow(&row);
    } while (row >! 0 && row <! 10);
    //while ((ans != 'Y') && (ans != 'N') && (ans != 'y') && (ans != 'n'));

    do // Input Column
    {
        passByColumn(&column);
    } while (column >! 0 && column <! 10);

    // Display the table
    cout << "\nTHE MULTIPLICATION TABLE:\n" << endl << "" << endl;

    for (int c = 1; c < row+1; c++)
    {
        for (int i = 1; i < column+1; i++)
        {
            cout << i * c << '\t';
        }
        cout << endl;
    }

    cin >> dummy;
    return 0;
}

int passByRow(int *x)
{
    cout << "Please enter a number of rows on the interval [1, 10]: ";
    cin >> *x;

    return *x;
}

int passByColumn(int *x)
{
    cout << "Please enter a number of columns on the interval [1, 10]: ";
    cin >> *x;

    return *x;
}
```

Comment: You have weird spacing. `row >! 0 && row <! 10` actually means `row > !0 && row < !10`. `!0` is 1 and `!10` is 0.

Comment: Instead  of `column >! 0 && column <! 10`, try `column < 1 || column > 10`.

Comment: @TonyD Post it as an answer

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `column >! 0 && column <! 10`, try `column < 1 || column > 10`.  Similar for `row`.  Find [some manner of documentation on C++ operators](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operators_in_C_and_C%2B%2B) instead of guessing....